# How to use variables in xsl:for-each but create the output later?

Tags: html, xslt-1.0

I'm struggling to get the output to display as required.

I run an xslt 1.0 file that parses every 5 seconds a xml file that contains statistical information.
every 15 minutes we get an additional file to parse which is pulled in as external source.
The parsing is fine but displaying the information fails miserably.
This is the section that creates the output:

```
<td>
  <table cellSpacing="0" border="1" cellPadding="2" style="background-color:lightblue;color:green;font-size:80%;">
    <xsl:for-each select="/DialStats/Countries">
      <!-- @Country = 15 min 2nd XML file / $Country = 5 sec prim XML file-->
      <xsl:if test="@Country = $Country">
          <xsl:for-each select="./Products">
            <!-- @Product = 15 min 2nd XML file / $Product = 5 sec prim XML file-->
            <xsl:if test="@Product = $Product">
              <xsl:for-each select="Dispositions">
                <xsl:variable name="TSB">
                  <xsl:if test="@Result = 'Tour / Sale / Booking'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Count"/>
                   </xsl:if>
                 </xsl:variable>
<!-- // set multiple variables:  -->
                 <xsl:variable name="ITF">
                   <xsl:if test="@Result = 'Internal Transfer'">
                     <xsl:value-of select="@Count"/>
                   </xsl:if>
                 </xsl:variable>

<!-- // Now generate the output:  -->
                 <xsl:choose>
                   <xsl:when test="string-length($TSB)=0 and string-length($NoAgent)=0">
                     <!-- Don't do anything -->
                   </xsl:when>  
                   <xsl:when test="string-length($TSB)!=0 and string-length($NoAgent)=0">
                     <tr>
                       <td>
                         <xsl:value-of select="$TSB"/>
                       </td>
                       <td> - </td>
                       <td>TSB</td>
                       <td>. .</td>
                       <td colspan="3"></td>
                     </tr>
                   </xsl:when>
                   <xsl:when test="string-length($TSB)=0 and string-length($NoAgent)!=0">
                     <tr>
                       <td colspan="3"></td>
                       <td>. .</td>
                       <td>
                         <xsl:value-of select="$NoAgent"/>
                       </td>
                       <td>-</td>
                       <td>No Agent</td>
                     </tr>
                   </xsl:when>
                   <xsl:otherwise>
                     <tr>
                       <td>
                         <xsl:value-of select="$TSB"/>
                       </td>
                       <td> - </td>
                       <td>TSB</td>
                       <td>. .</td>
                       <td>
                         <xsl:value-of select="$NoAgent"/>
                       </td>
                       <td>-</td>
                       <td>No Agent</td>
                     </tr>
                   </xsl:otherwise>
                 </xsl:choose>
<!-- // Generate more of the output:  -->
<!-- // Last section  -->
                  <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="string-length($OTH)=0">
                      <!-- Don't do anything -->
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="string-length($OTH)!=0">
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <xsl:value-of select="$OTH"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>-</td>
                        <td>OTH</td>
                        <td>. .</td>
                        <td colspan="3"></td>
                      </tr>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                      <!-- Nothing to do -->
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                  </xsl:choose>
               </xsl:for-each>
             </xsl:if>
           </xsl:for-each>
         </xsl:if>
       </xsl:for-each>
   </table>
 </td>
```

This generates a table however due to how the XML file contains information it is not consistently in the same spot, it might not be there at all. 
I want the information to show on the same place for different blocks.

This is how I want it to display

```
  x - TSB  | x - NoAgent
  x - OSA  | x - LO
  x - IP   | x - UEE
  x - MES  | x - SIT
  x - NoVM | x - RNA
  x - NSR  | x - ITF
  x - OTH
```

If the value is 0 then I leave the info blank if both are blank then I want to leave the whole line out.

This is how it however displays

```
9 - MES  |   
3 - NoVM |  
7 - IP   |  
         | 5 - LO 
6 - OTH  |  
         | 6 - RNA 
         | 4 - SIT 
3 -  TSB |
```

Is there a way to created first all variables before creating the output?
I tried that but then I end up in the problem that the variable is out-of-scope.

Looking forward to suggestions

The XML looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <DialStats>
    <Countries Country="France">
     <Products Product="Office">
       <Dispositions Result="Agent Voicemail / Message" Count="11" />
       <Dispositions Result="Did Not Leave Voicemail" Count="37" />
       <Dispositions Result="Information Provided" Count="13" />
       <Dispositions Result="Lost Opportunity" Count="1" />
       <Dispositions Result="No Agent Available" Count="1" />
       <Dispositions Result="Ring No Answer" Count="6" />
       <Dispositions Result="SIT Tone" Count="3" />
       <Dispositions Result="Tour / Sale / Booking" Count="7" />
     </Products>
   </Countries>
   <Countries Country="Italy">
     <Products Product="Office">
       <Dispositions Result="Did Not Leave Voicemail" Count="1" />
       <Dispositions Result="Information Provided" Count="6" />
       <Dispositions Result="Non-Sales Related" Count="1" />
       <Dispositions Result="Other" Count="6" />
       <Dispositions Result="Ring No Answer" Count="7" />
       <Dispositions Result="SIT Tone" Count="5" />
       <Dispositions Result="Updated Existing Enquiry" Count="13" />
     </Products>
   </Countries>
   <Countries Country="Netherlands">
     <Products Product="Office">
       <Dispositions Result="Agent Voicemail / Message" Count="1" />
       <Dispositions Result="Information Provided" Count="17" />
       <Dispositions Result="Ring No Answer" Count="3" />
       <Dispositions Result="Tour / Sale / Booking" Count="2" />
     </Products>
  </Countries>
 </DialStats>
```

Many different Countries possible.

Thanks
[image: Output]

Comment: Please provide an example of the XML input. It would be most helpful if you could minimize the code of both XML and XSLT to only what's necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand the logic of the requested transformation. I suggest again you simplify the question.

Comment: The issue is that every run in the for:each loop it will find one of the dispositions, which than is processed in the build of the table. Based on the order the disposition is in the XML it will be found. This will not allow me to build the table in the way I need it to be displayed. What I basically need is all the variables be set before I build the table, but when I try that I get out of scope, so how can I pull all dispositions and then build the table?

Comment: That shouldn't be difficult, but I don't understand what you mean by "*if the value is 0 then I leave the info blank if both are blank then I want to leave the whole line out.*" What is both? If you leave the whole line out, then the positions of the data will not be constant, as you say you want. -- It's also not clear what do you want to do with the various countries: are they to be all summed together?

Comment: the XML not always has data for a particular variable, so that one would be empty. when creating the output I put 2 variables on one line, either or both can be empty, the latter I will not generate two empty cells but just omit the output totally.

Comment: the information is part of a much bigger piece, I have added a picture in how this is displayed. Each country has a break down on stats (updated every 5 seconds) that is complemented by the output from a 15 minute updated file

Comment: You haven't really answered my questions (and the screenshot doesn't convey much). If you skip empty lines, then the information below it will move up. Is that what you want? -- It seems to me you might be better of using CSS for final formatting of the data (such as placing tables side by side).

Comment: To keep the output as compressed as possible I would like to remove lines or to have a fixed 3 column layout (rather than the 2 I try to achieve now) the screenshot shows how the result sets in blue relating to this question are broken down to match country and product as one of your previous questions if I wanted it broken down by country. The first 9 lines of code do break it down that way, matching it with the data of the 5 second XML file.

I hope this helps?

Comment: I am afraid at this point I have no idea what your question is. I have edited my answer, perhaps it fits what you want.

Comment: unfortunately your <xsl:template match="/"> breaks the whole xsl that is already having a <xsl:template match="/"> and causes no output to be generated. thanks for your help, but I can't get to what I need with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***(edited)***

I would suggest you try a different approach. The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="categories">
    <category row="1">Agent Voicemail / Message</category>
    <category row="1">Did Not Leave Voicemail</category>
    <category row="1">Information Provided</category>
    <category row="1">Lost Opportunity</category>
    <category row="1">No Agent Available</category>
    <category row="1">Ring No Answer</category>
    <category row="2">SIT Tone</category>
    <category row="2">Tour / Sale / Booking</category>
    <category row="2">Non-Sales Related</category>
    <category row="2">Other</category>
    <category row="2">Updated Existing Enquiry</category>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="col-set" select="exsl:node-set($categories)/category" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="DialStats/Countries">
        <xsl:variable name="country" select="." />
        <table border="1" style="width:30%; display:inline-block">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="{count($col-set[@row='1'])}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$country/@Country"/>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="$col-set[@row='1']">
                    <th><xsl:value-of select="."/></th>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="$col-set[@row='1']">
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$country/Products/Dispositions[@Result=current()]/@Count"/>
                    </td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="$col-set[@row='2']">
                    <th><xsl:value-of select="."/></th>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="$col-set[@row='2']">
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$country/Products/Dispositions[@Result=current()]/@Count"/>
                    </td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your input example, will produce:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table border="1" style="width:30%; display:inline-block">
   <tr>
      <th colspan="6">France</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th>Agent Voicemail / Message</th>
      <th>Did Not Leave Voicemail</th>
      <th>Information Provided</th>
      <th>Lost Opportunity</th>
      <th>No Agent Available</th>
      <th>Ring No Answer</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>6</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th>SIT Tone</th>
      <th>Tour / Sale / Booking</th>
      <th>Non-Sales Related</th>
      <th>Other</th>
      <th>Updated Existing Enquiry</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td/>
      <td/>
      <td/>
   </tr>
</table>
<table border="1" style="width:30%; display:inline-block">
   <tr>
      <th colspan="6">Italy</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th>Agent Voicemail / Message</th>
      <th>Did Not Leave Voicemail</th>
      <th>Information Provided</th>
      <th>Lost Opportunity</th>
      <th>No Agent Available</th>
      <th>Ring No Answer</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td/>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td/>
      <td/>
      <td>7</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th>SIT Tone</th>
      <th>Tour / Sale / Booking</th>
      <th>Non-Sales Related</th>
      <th>Other</th>
      <th>Updated Existing Enquiry</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td/>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>13</td>
   </tr>
</table>
<table border="1" style="width:30%; display:inline-block">
   <tr>
      <th colspan="6">Netherlands</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th>Agent Voicemail / Message</th>
      <th>Did Not Leave Voicemail</th>
      <th>Information Provided</th>
      <th>Lost Opportunity</th>
      <th>No Agent Available</th>
      <th>Ring No Answer</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td/>
      <td>17</td>
      <td/>
      <td/>
      <td>3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th>SIT Tone</th>
      <th>Tour / Sale / Booking</th>
      <th>Non-Sales Related</th>
      <th>Other</th>
      <th>Updated Existing Enquiry</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td/>
      <td>2</td>
      <td/>
      <td/>
      <td/>
   </tr>
</table>
```

rendered as:

[image]

The table's structure is constant and does not depend on the incoming data.

Comment: When implemented in the template at the place where the original code is, I get an error on the <xsl:template match="/"> with an out-of-scope error for $categories. this needs to fit in with a template that processes the external file data       <xsl:template match="/" name="ExternalData" mode="my-mode">
          <xsl:param name="WGroup" />
          <xsl:param name="CSII" />

Comment: I create a call template stats, named the first template stats and added 2 parameters to address categories and stats, however the second template category throws an error on the $stats it not being a node set